# Reading the contents inside the comment lines using Regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as

```
/* @TS 1 This is the comment
for method1

/* @TS 2 This is the comment
for method2*/
```

I need to map each index value(1,2) to that content like Eg
1 -> This is the comment for method1

**I wrote the below Python Program using the regular
Expression**

```
regex  = r"/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*([^/]|[\r\n])))*\*/"
```

Is there any regular expression that will group number as one group and content after(:) as one group?

Comment: Do you mean you want to obtain a dictionary with keys that are digits after `@TS`?

Comment: yes, Instead of If condition directly I can put group1 as key and group2 as value to the dictionary,

Comment: So, you will also need to remove all `*` at the start of each comment line, right?

Comment: Yes,that I will remove using replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
s = "/* @TS 1 : This is the comment\n* for method1\n*/\n/* @TS 2 : This is the comment\n* for method2\n*/"
rx = r'/\*+\s*@TS\s*(\d+)\s*:([^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/)'
d = {}
for match in re.finditer(rx, s):
    d[match.group(1)] = re.sub(r"(?:^|[\r\n]+)\s*\*\s*", "", match.group(2)[:-2].strip())

print(d) # => {'1': 'This is the commentfor method1', '2': 'This is the commentfor method2'}
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/07rrtB)

There are several things to note here.

**Pattern details**

- `/\*+` - match the comment start `/*` and any 0+ `*`s after
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `@TS` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\s*:` - 0+ whitespaces and `:`
- `([^*]*\*+` - (Group 2 start): match 0+ characters other than `*` followed with 1+ literal `*`
- `(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `[^/*][^*]*\*+` - not a `/` or `*` (matched with `[^/*]`) followed with 0+ non-asterisk characters (`[^*]*`) followed with 1+ asterisks (`\*+`)
- `/)` - closing `/` (Group 2 end)

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J0mdfv/1)

**Code details**

An empty dictionary is defined with `d = {}`. Then, all matches are found with `re.finditer`, and `match.group(1)` is the key, and `match.group(2)` contains the value that needs "trimming" a bit. Last 2 chars are removed with `[:-2]` (as these are `*/`), then the value is stripped from whitespace (`.strip()`) and then, with the `(?:^|[\r\n]+)\s*\*\s*` pattern we remove all `*` with enclosing whitespace at the start of string/lines.

Comment: hey, Thank you for your help. I am expecting the same result .your code snippet is removing * also